# Convert vector from cylindrical to cartesian Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, coordinates, wolfram-mathematica

I know about the `pol2cart` function in Matlab but I don't think it is what I want, or maybe I don't know how to use it to have it return what I want.

Say you have the following vector:

[image: here].

In Wolfram Mathematica, for example, you can write something like:

[image: this]

and it returns the cartesian coordinates of the above vector.

The question is: How do I achieve something like this in Matlab? It would have been much easier if I just had to work with numbers and have those as inputs for `pol2cart`, but over here I need my vector displayed similarly to the output of the `TransformedField` function.

Thanks,
Irina

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing magical in Mathematica's operation.  It's merely leveraging the [change-of-basis between cylindrical and Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Vector_fields).  Here is a quick-and-dirty implementation to perform something similar using symbolic variables:

```matlab
function vcar = cyl2car(vcyl)
    %
    %   The elements of vcyl are expected to be order [v_r ; v_theta ; v_z] such that
    %   vcyl = v_r * rhat + v_theta * thetahat + v_z * zhat.
    %
    %   The element of vcar will then be in the order: [v_x ; v_y ; v_z] such that
    %   vcar = v_x * xhat + v_y * yhat + v_z * zhat.
    %
    %   For symbolic input, the expected symbolic symbols are [r,theta,z] for cylindrical
    %   and [x,y,z] for Cartesian.
    %

    %   Declarations  and change-of-basis
    syms x y z r theta xhat yhat zhat rhat thetahat;
    rhat     =  x/sqrt(x^2 + y^2) * xhat + y/sqrt(x^2 + y^2) * yhat;
    thetahat = -y/sqrt(x^2 + y^2) * xhat + x/sqrt(x^2 + y^2) * yhat;

    %   Substitute and simplify
    temp = simplify(subs(vcyl,[r,theta],[sqrt(x^2+y^2),atan(y/x)]));
    temp = expand(sum(temp .* [rhat ; thetahat ; zhat]));

    %   Assign
    vcar  = sym(0)*vcyl;
    [c,t] = coeffs(temp,[xhat,yhat,zhat]);
    if (length(t)>=1)
        vcar(1) = c(1);
    end
    if (length(t)>=2)
        vcar(2) = c(2);
    end
    if (length(t)>=3)
        vcar(3) = c(3);
    end    
end
```

Which returns a similar expression to that from Mathematica:

```matlab
>> vcyl = [0 ; sym(64)*sym(10^-7)*sym(pi)/(sym(2)*r) ; 0];
>> vcarsym = cyl2car(vcyl)
vcarsym =
 -(pi*y)/(312500*(x^2 + y^2))
  (pi*x)/(312500*(x^2 + y^2))
                            0
```